# Not found 'AppKit/AppKit.h' when build converted iOS project using Windows Bridge for iOS

Tags: ios, winobjc

With *Windows Bridge for iOS*, I converted my iOS project to Windows App using *vsimporter* (follow Microsoft's guide: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC)

But when I try to build the project, It shows Fatal Error: **'AppKit/AppKit.h' file not found** at

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: AppKit is macOS only. Thus, it can't compile for iOS.

Comment: Thanks. AppKit is for Mac; UIKit is for iOS. But maybe they will also not found when building Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app on Windows?

Comment: Do you have searched through your sources, if there exists probably an include for AppKit? Probably inside of an `#if`?